# How can I manipulate a decimal or integer column in a callback before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am having a model `Factsheet` which has some decimal columns, for entering some $ values(price). I need to be able to enter values like `$1,000,000.00` and calculate the original value from them before saving. If I do the save, before any formatting, it will save it as `1.00` as `"$1,000,000.00".to_f = 1.0` I was trying to do a before_save callback, and extract the digits and dots only from the column before saving it. Here is how I went about it:

```
class Factsheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :convert_to_decimal

  def convert_to_decimal
    self.shopping_center_size = decimal_value(shopping_center_size)
    self.cam = decimal_value(cam)
    self.tax = decimal_value(tax)
    #... some other manipulations
  end

  def decimal_value(string)
    string ? string.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, "") : string
  end
end
```

But, this code is not working as Rails convert the parameters into `BigDecimal` (I believe it performs `to_f` to the string). So I am getting `NoMethod gsub for BigDecimal` when I execute this code. I know I can manipulate the `params` in the controller itself before saving, or pass the `params` to a class method in the model and manipulate it there. But, both these options doesnt seem right. Is there anyway, I can manipulate them in the callback itself?

Controller:

```
def FactsheetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @factsheet = Factsheet.new
  end

  def create
    @factsheet = Factsheet.new(params[:factsheet])
    if @factsheet.save
      flash[:notice] = "Factsheet created successfully"
      redirect_to @factsheet
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @factsheet = Factsheet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @factsheet = Factsheet.find(params[:id])
    if @factsheet.update_attributes(params[:factsheet])
      flash[:notice] = "Factsheet updated successfully"
      redirect_to @factsheet
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

View:

_form.html.erb

```
# Here user should be able to enter values like $1,000,000.00
# and it should be correctly saved to database as 1000000.0
<%= form.text_field :cam %>
<%= form.text_field :tax %>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What would be the correct "original value" for "$1,00,00.00"?

Comment: you might have virtual attribute in your model (like `:str_cam, :str_tax`) and use it inside your form to get values of `:cam` and `:tax` however you have to convert them back in your views

Comment: just a comment, your input seems to be wrong: $1,00,00.00 you seem to be missing 0s: $1,000,000.00

Comment: @mosch..the correct value for `$1,000,000.00` will be `1000000.0`..@corroded..you are right, I missed 0s..edited

Comment: If Rails want a string, give it a string: `string ? string.to_s.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, "").to_f : string`

Comment: @arnep..`decimal_value(string)` is a method written by me..I expected the attributes of the model instance to be same as that provided from the `params` in the controller, but it seems Rails is doing a typecasting according to the database column type, before giving to the model. I will edit my question giving more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the set method of each field in the model, like this:

```
def shopping_center_size=(num)
   self[:shopping_center_size] = decimal_value(num)
end

def cam=(num)
   self[:cam] = decimal_value(num)
end

def tax=(num)
   self[:tax] = decimal_value(num)
end
```